# Jenkins Pipeline - Workflow CPS plugin JAR dependencies

Tags: jenkins, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml, jenkins-pipeline

I'm implementing unit tests for code used in a [Jenkins Pipeline Shared Groovy Library](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin). Specically, I need to mock the `steps` object available in the Jenkinsfile, which is an instance of `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL`. In my Gradle build I've specified a dependency like so:

```
testCompile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow', name: 'workflow-cps', version: '2.30', ext: 'jar'
```

which is the project hosting the class above. Without specifying the `ext` as a JAR, Gradle retrieves the `.hpi` file since this is the packaging defined in the project's pom.xml; obviously I need to override this and fetch the JAR for my project. However, in doing this Gradle does not download the transitive dependencies of the `workflow-cps` JAR and I find myself having to populate my build.gradle with all the dependencies determined via trial and error. Is there a way to retrieve the transitive dependencies, or is this a limitation of the workflow-cps project and how it defines its pom.xml?

Comment: What test framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spock. I've kept the `vars` directory very lightweight and added the complex logic to `src` so I can test the library with standard unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

The CPS class you're wanting to mock won't contain methods/variables introduced by plugins or your workflow lib, so this approach probably won't be fully satisfying.

Facing the same challenge I took the pragmatic approach of making my own TestScript interface in my test sources and Mock that, and not typing the script reference in classes.

The drawbacks are not having IDE code inspection for stuff referencing the script, and having to manually add signatures to TestScript as I add tests (which is also error-prone, since I have manually ensure that those signatures match).

But it works, and avoids getting dragged into plugin dependency hell.